# android JSON parsing How to make two http Connection one after the other

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, url

Im using Rotten Tomatoes api and for some reason if i want to get more information about a movie like the movie director or the studio I need another http page. this is the url that im getting movie-info. from this JSON i get the id ( "self": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771205893.json").
and i want to use that id- i want to make another http connection to that specific url and get more information about each movie.
this is the movie-info JSON:

```
{

"total": 591,

"movies": [{

"title": "Jack and Jill",

"year": 2011,

"runtime": "",

"release_dates": {"theater": "2011-11-11"},

"ratings": {

  "critics_score": -1,

  "audience_score": 90

},

"synopsis": "",

"posters": {

},

"abridged_cast": [

  {

    "name": "Al Pacino",

    "characters": []

  },

  {

    "name": "Adam Sandler",

    "characters": []

  },

  {

    "name": "Katie Holmes",

    "characters": []

  }

],

"links": {

  "self": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771205893.json",

}

}],
```

This is my code:

```
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                // convert the String response to a JSON object,
                // because JSON is the response format Rotten Tomatoes uses
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                // fetch the array of movies in the response
                JSONArray movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("movies");

                // add each movie's title to an array
                movieTitles = new String[movies.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                    movieTitles[i] = movie.getString("title");
                }

                try {
                    movieId = new String[movies.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                        movieId[i] = movie.getString("id");

                    }
```

After i get the movieId i want to get only the movie id that the user has pressed 
so i use :

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    AfterClickingMovieFromInternet.class);

            i.putExtra("movieName", movieTitles[position]);
            getMovieInfo( movieId[position]);
```

and in the getMovieInfo( movieId[position]) im trying to make a second connection to the api but for some reason it wont execute..... 
if anyone got any idea ill be happy to know!

Comment: Have you tried to Toast or Log the e.toString();? Remember you are not able to Toast in the doInBackground you'll do it in onPostExcute

Comment: i try to sent the string given to anther activity but the string sent was null

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with 2 consecutive connections?
Did you check libraries?

I would recommend this one - https://github.com/kodart/Httpzoid
Is uses GSON internally and provides API that works with objects. All JSON details are hidden.

```
Http http = HttpFactory.create(context);
http.get("http://example.com/users")
    .handler(new ResponseHandler<User[]>() {
        @Override
        public void success(User[] users, HttpResponse response) {
        }
    }).execute();
```